# What is a good technique to get as far as possible with the Plane?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I love being as far as possible from the plane path. And sometimes, the couple of houses I want to go to are just a little too far.

So what are techniques to optimize how far you go when freefalling/using the parachute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do to get the maximum horizontal movement after jumping out of the plane is move my mouse upward so that my character is spread out completely (while holding <kbd>W</kbd> obviously).  This will slow your decent down to the slowest speed possible since your body is providing more resistance against the air (as it would in real life), while maximizing the distance you move across the map.

Once my parachute deploys, I hold the <kbd>W</kbd> key in to keep my speed up, while also moving horizontally.  This however will make you reach the ground quicker.  I find that pressing the <kbd>W</kbd> key and releasing it at about half second intervals allows you to keep your speed up while also lowering the rate at which I fall to the ground.

Combing these two techniques allows me to get pretty far away from the plane's original path. I would say it is certainly a good way to get some distance between you and the plane's path.

Comment: I guess you'd get even further if you open your parachute as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to get away from the plane's path is by travelling perpendicular to it. If you place a marker where you want to go and position your view so that the plane wing tips are lined up (looking at the plane sideways), your compass heading will line up with your marker when your path to the marked position is perpendicular to the plane's path. You can use the same method to determine what the plane's flight path will be by placing markers until they line up with your compass heading when looking forward of the plane.

In terms of "optimizing" where you go, if your objective is to land as far as possible from your jumping point, you can just pull the chute to go farther and continue on the perpendicular path. However, in PUBG there is usually an emphasis on speed, since landing in your chosen location before other players means you can get resources before them which makes you more likely to survive. This generally makes pulling the chute early a poor choice, as it is a slow way to get to the ground. There are plenty of videos on different strategies/locations, but if you want to emphasise distance from the plane you can look up to maximise your non-chute air-time until you think you're the right distance to pull the chute.